# No sound via HDMI. Intel 82801H, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, hdmi, soundcard

I have just reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits in my laptop. a Dell XPS M1330.

With previous versions it used to ask me to install additional drivers (A Realtek card, i don't remember very well). But this time it seems not to need it any more.

Any way sound works ok thru laptop's speakers but i don't get it working in my TV via HDMI as it used to work. Actually there is no HDMI option in the sound settings.

```
 $ aplay -l
   **** Lista de PLAYBACK dispositivos hardware ****
   tarjeta 0: Intel [HDA Intel], dispositivo 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
     Subdispositivos: 1/1
     Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
   tarjeta 0: Intel [HDA Intel], dispositivo 1: STAC92xx Digital [STAC92xx Digital]
     Subdispositivos: 1/1
     Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
   tarjeta 0: Intel [HDA Intel], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
     Subdispositivos: 1/1
     Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0


   $ lspci | grep "Audio" # if no hits, change to 'audio' or remove ' | grep "Audio" '
   00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev    02)

   $ sudo lshw -C multimedia[sudo] password for keroak: 
     *-multimedia            
          descripción: Audio device
          producto: 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller
          fabricante: Intel Corporation
          id físico: 1b
          información del bus: pci@0000:00:1b.0
          versión: 02
          anchura: 64 bits
          reloj: 33MHz
          capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
          configuración: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
          recursos: irq:47 memoria:fe9fc000-fe9fffff

   $ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* | grep CodecCodec: SigmaTel STAC9228
   Codec: Silicon Image SiI1392 HDMI
```

Comment: I also run a sund test and i was able to hear the sound thru the TV.
$ speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,3
speaker-test 1.0.25

Playback device is hw:0,3
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 64 to 16384
Period size range from 32 to 8192
Using max buffer size 16384
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 4096
was set buffer_size = 16384
 0 - Front Left
 1 - Front Right
Time per period = 5,632161
 0 - Front Left
 1 - Front Right

Answer (score 0):

Turn the laptop on with the HDMI cable connected that it will enable the HDMI Audio on Sound Control Panel.

I have a Inspiron 14 (Intel board) with the same problem...

Comment: Thanks.. but i already had the cable connected on startup. Finally, I installed another distribution and it works properly.

Comment: Did you try also to "mirror" the screens, that it, configure both monitors (from laptop and TV) to show the same content ?

Comment: No, i didn't...